# Q: Is it possible to include orientation in this media query approach?

Tags: css, sass

I was wondering how I can specify the media-query orientation in this nested apporach in sccs.

I'm using Eduardo's media-query approach - is it possible to include orientation here?

Edit:
Because orientation isn't mentioned at all there, and if im trying something like this `@include media(">=768px", "<=1023px", orientation: landscape)` it doesn't compile.

https://eduardoboucas.github.io/include-media/

https://css-tricks.com/approaches-media-queries-sass/

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    top: 26%;
    @include media(">=768px", "<=1023px") {
      top: 19%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about the nested approach
`@media all and (orientation: portrait) { ... }`
This will work . Try just using only the oreintation.